# Simple web crawler / scraper for deals

Tags: web, automation

For fun and maybe for profit, i want to implement the following:

1. scheduled or manually triggered process that logs into all my bank accounts
2. process knows bank site structure, and goes through "cashback/partner deals" pages
3. all deal information is collected in one place and in one format
4. when i'm going to buy something, i can quickly see if any of my cards has a special offer for that place. so that i can pay with the card that offers the best deal. ideally, this should happen on my android phone. that doesn't imply a standalone app though, e.g. you can search inside an email or googledoc or anything.

any ideas on implementation? don't limit yourself. suggest crazy things, as long as they work.

PS i did look for an existing website that offers something similar, but they all seem to focus on cards themselves rather than on specific deals for stores.

Comment: This does not sound simple.

Comment: @orde, maybe it should read "simplest way to implement a web crawler that does this".

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the bank website, your code may need to be able to execute JavaScript to interact with it.  Take a look at CasperJS for the web scraping part.

Comment: yes, i had some experience with casperjs. can you elaborate on your idea a little bit?

Comment: Sorry this formatting is not right, I am trying to improve it now.  1. Cron job.  2. This is the hardest part - the structures of the various banking sites won't be that similar I think. Figure it out for one banking site, then a second site to see how much code can re-used.  3. Common deal data stored on a mobile browser friendly web site.  4. Browse that common deal data from your phone when you are shopping (not sure how that searching would work).